# $0^0$ vs $lim_{q\rightarrow 0}0^q$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know this is rather old and contentious topic in mathematics and some sources say $0^0=1$ others that it is indeterminate. And I understand the role, how fast limits are of $x$ and $y$ in $x^y$. But how about $0^0$ in the sense $0^q$ as $q\rightarrow 0$, in other words: $\lim_{q\rightarrow 0}0^q$?
The feeling says it should be zero. Mathematica says that as well:

```
Limit[0^q, q -> 0]
0
```

But why?

Comment: while evaluating limit at a point, you always check the value at points arbitarily close to that point but never at that point and since $0^q = 0$ for all $q \ne 0$, the limit is equal to zero as well.

Comment: and moreover remember that $0^0 := \lim_{x \to 0} x^0 = 1$, that is $0^0$ is defined in this way.

Comment: There is no issue. One can perfectly well define $0^0$ to be $1$, and there are some good reasons to do so. That has no effect on the limiting behaviour of $x^y$  as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, and $y$ approaches $0$. That behaviour depends on the path along which  $x$ and $y$ approach $0$. Depending on the path, the limit may or may not exist, and when it exists the value can be many different things. No problem, it just means that $x^y$ is not continuous at $x=0$, $y=0$.

Comment: In my opinion: $0^0$ is simply indeterminate (undefined). In particular contexts, people sometimes make a convention of letting that symbol stand for $1$ (for example, in a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$, we want its value at $x=0$ to be $c_n$); if one does this, one has to know what operations preserve this convention—not all of them will.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a comment. But since I cannot post figures in the comments section, I post them in the answer section. The figures come from the paper : "ZERO TO THE ZERO-TH POWER" : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power

[image]
[image]